# multiple autocomplete in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am working on jquery multiple autocomplete in codeigniter means if user entered the alphabet then appropriate result should be displayed and after selected answer if he entered another input then by adding coma another result should be added accordingly but when i am entering any alphabet then no result as well as the code is not working .please any one help me out of this.Thank you..

Below is my code..

**Js code and html**

```
   <script>
   $(this).ready( function() {  
    function split( val ) {
      return val.split( /,\s'*/' );
    }

    function extractLast( term ) {
      return split( term ).pop();
    }


    $( "#multiple_key_skills" ).autocomplete({
     minLength: 1, 

      source: function(req,add ) {
      //alert("ashdgd");
        $.ajax({
                                     url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/userdashboard/getmultiplekeyskills",
                            data: req,
                            dataType: 'json', 
                            //type: "post",
                            cache: false,
                            success: function (data){
                                    //alert(data);
                                      if(data.response =="true"){ 

                                        add(data.message); 

                                            console.log(data);
                                        }
                                         },
                                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) 
                            {
                                alert(thrownError);
                            }
            });

              },
      select: function( event, ui ) {
                // Add the selected term appending to the current values with a comma
                var terms = split( this.value );
                // remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                // add the selected item
                terms.push( ui.item.value );
                // join all terms with a comma
                this.value = terms.join( ", " );
                return false;
              },
      focus: function() {
               // prevent value inserted on focus when navigating the drop down list
               return false;
             }
    });
  });
 </script>
 <body>
 <input id="multiple_key_skills" type="text" name="multiple_key_skills">
 </body>
 </html>
```

**controller**

```
 funtion getmultiplekeyskills()
 {
     $keyword = $this->input->post('term'); 
    //echo json_encode($keyword);
        $query= $this -> dashboard_model-> getmultiplekeyskills($keyword);
       // echo json_encode($data);
        $data['response'] = 'false';
         if( ! empty($query) )  
    {  
        $data['response'] = 'true'; //Set response  
        $data['message'] = array(); //Create array  
        foreach( $query as $row )  
        {  
            $data['message'][] = array(   
                                    'id'=>$row->id,  
                                    'value' => $row->key_skill,  

                                 );  //Add a row to array  
        }
        //echo json_encode("fdszf");  
    }  
    if('IS_AJAX')  
    {  
       echo json_encode($data); //echo json string if ajax request  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        $this->load->view('profile_view',$data); //Load html view of search results  
    } 

}

 }
```

**Model**

```
   function getmultiplekeyskills()
    {
   $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM key_skills WHERE key_skill LIKE ('$keyword%')") ;
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: I guess for this you have to split the string in input and then send it to server for checking , or split that string in php and then send only last text to check in database.

Comment: 1. Remove dataType: 'post',  and set dataType: 'json',
2 You are sending request using ajax so your data will be return in json. Try this correction.

Comment: @Jazz i did that ..but still its not working.

Comment: can you show me which error you are getting?

Comment: @Jazz . I am not getting any error.